# Setting Hyper and Super modifiers for certain keys with setxkbmap or xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb, setxkbmap

Problem: I want to modify/redefine my keyboard layout (pc105 se) so that when I press certain keys with mod3 (super) and mod4 (hyper), a different character is returned than usual.

E.g.

Keycode 61 produces 'minus' (-) when pressed normally and 'underscore' (_) when pressed with shift. When pressed with the first modifier group (AltGr) 'dead_belowdot' and 'dead_abovedot' is produced (without/with shift).

What I want is a left paranthesis or right paranthesis (without/with shift) when I press the key with the Super (win) key also pressed, and slash/backslash for the Hyper key (which I have configured to Caps Lock).

I have tried to add a `.Xmodmap` to my home directory and run it with 
`xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` using the following syntax

```
keycode 61 = minus underscore a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
```

However, that will cause AltGr to result in c/d, while win/caps lock still only results in -/_

I have also tried modifying /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se directly and tried the following changes:

```
key <BKSL>  { [apostrophe, asterisk, acute, multiply], [a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h], [i,j,k,l]};
```

But all that happens is ' * ´ × ' * ' * (for normal, altgr, win and caps lock respectively).
I have also tried

```
key <BKSL>  { [apostrophe, asterisk, acute, multiply, a,b,c,d, e,f,g,h, i,j,k,l]};
```

But as soon as there are more than four specified fields, it seems to break the key totaly, and the key reverts to default pc105 (us?) behaviour.

As I have failed to find anything on stackoverflow, superuser or google on how to deal with my scenario, I ask here.

This is my `xmodmap -pm`

```
xmodmap:  up to 3 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Hyper_L (0x42),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: If you find anything could you please post your answer here?  (that is: answering your own question).  I'm amazed by how complicated such a trivial task seems to be and there's hardly any info on the net.  It's just crazy.

Comment: I will. But for now, I'm still only at the stage of trial-and-error and constant manual reading.

Comment: I'm still curious why the default AltGr won't work for all keys the same way... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249122/why-do-my-xmodmap-binds-involving-altgr-only-work-on-some-keys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two years later, I am finally proud to answer my own question.

I have found the easiest, most reliable and most extendable method is to solely rely on `xmodmap`.

### 1. Get keycodes of special keys

Run `xev` to determine the key code of keys you wish to use as mode switchers. Then press the keys you are interested in and note down the `keycode`

```
$ xev
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x2a6, subw 0x0, time 1221887800, (885,743), root:(3447,805),
    state 0x2010, keycode 66 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The keycode is on the third line, keycode 66.

For me, these were the keys I was particularly interested in, and their corresponding key codes for me:

- `Caps Lock`, keycode 66
- `Pause|Break`, keycode 128
- `Left Windows key`, keycode 133
- `Num Lock`, key code 77

### 2. Set switcher keys

This is the setup I have opted for, but you can choose your own setup. I have saved this to a file `$HOME/.xmodmap`.

```
~/.xmodmap
keycode  66 = Mode_switch
keycode 127 = Multi_key
keycode 133 = Super_L
...
```

This way I have bound `Caps Lock` to `Mode_switch`, `Pause Break` to `Compose` and the left `Win` key to `Super_L`. The `Compose` key is particularly useful as it allows two keys to be combined to ligature. E.g. `Compose` followed by `T` and `M` results in the trademark sign `™`.

### 3. Get current keymap bindings of `xmodmap`

In order to not destroy my keyboard layout, I wanted to keep my keys as close to my original layout as possible. In order to do that I printed the current keymap and looked for the keycodes I wanted to change.

```
$ xmodmap -pke | ag 'keycode  51'
```

Off course, you could just as easily use `grep` or `ack`, depending on the tool you prefer to use.

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 'keycode  41' 
$ xmodmap -pke | ack 'keycode  31'
```

The output of this is in the same format as the one you specify in your `~/.xmodmap` like this:

```
keycode  31 = i I i I rightarrow idotless rightarrow idotless i I rightarrow idotless i I rightarrow idotless
```

### 4. Backup your existing `xmodmap`

Just in case something goes wrong, it's never a bad Idea to have your current `xmodmap` available to fall back to easily.

```
$ xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap.bak
```

### 5. Add characters to 2nd, 3rd, 4th level of your keys

As far as I have understood, the format of the `.xmodmap` file is like this:

```
keycode <keycode> = <1st level> <Shift+1st> <2nd level> <shift+2nd> <3rd level> <shift+3rd level> <4th level> <shift+4th> ...
```

Now, I don't understand all those levels but `Mode_Switch` (`Caps Lock` in my case) will give you level 2 and `Alt Gr` gives me level 3, and that is pretty much all I am interested in so I left the rest of that line as it was in my `~/.xmodmap.bak` and just changed the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th columns (level 2 and 3, plus shift) to valid characters ([See here for a list of valid characters](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap)).

```
~/.xmodmap
...
keycode  51 = apostrophe asterisk dollar ampersand acute multiply acute multiply apostrophe asterisk acute multiply apostrophe asterisk acute multiply
keycode  59 = comma semicolon parenleft parenright dead_cedilla dead_ogonek dead_cedilla dead_ogonek comma semicolon dead_cedilla dead_ogonek comma semicolon dead_cedilla dead_ogonek
keycode  60 = period colon bracketleft bracketright periodcentered dead_abovedot periodcentered dead_abovedot period colon periodcentered dead_abovedot period colon periodcentered dead_abovedot
keycode  61 = minus underscore braceleft braceright slash backslash braceleft braceright
keycode  65 = space space space space space underscore space space
...
```

### 6. Test your `.xmodmap`

Now let `xmodmap` execute your `.xmodmap` and test your brand new keyboard layout.

```
$ xmodmap /home/user/.xmodmap
```

### 7. Make sure your keyboard layout is loaded on x init

I added this to my `$HOME/.xinitrc`:

```
~/.xinitrc
...
[-f $HOME/.xmodmap] && xmodmap $HOME/.xmodmap
...
```

I hope this was helpful!